# What kind of wire is this?

Tags: wire

It's black, with white in the middle, and copper around the white.  Any ideas?

I have a picture but not sure how to add it...

Comment: If you add a link to a picture, someone will come along and edit it into your question.

Comment: See [this meta question](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/523/2196) for instructions to add a picture to your post.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds an awful lot like [coaxial cable.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coaxial_cable)

[image]

This is used in cable TV and rather old computer network cables.  While not directly hazardous, homes with it have been statistically linked to high cable TV bills and an obsession with something called "Game of Thrones".

Answer (score 2):

If it has any wire down the middle of the inner 'white' then its probably coaxial cable consisting of:

- center core conductor
- dielectric
- braided or foil shield
- outer insulation

But if it only has the copper around the inner 'white' then its probably a super-flexible wire consisting of:

- Inner strength member (nylon/glass-fiber)
- braided or spiral-wound conductor
- outer insulation